# Grouped Bar Chart with negative value d3

Tags: d3.js

first time asking here.

I would like to modify this code here https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3887051 so that it will show negative values.

I have only managed to get the y axis to show correct negative values by changing this line

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);
```

to be:

```
y.domain([ d3.min(data, function(d) { return d3.min(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);
```

But that only takes care of the y axis, I cant get anything to change on the x axis.

I have looked everywhere online - but there's only stacked bar chart with negative, not grouped bar chart with negative.

Please kindly help.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The x axis in that example is a categorical axis that is determined by the values for `State`. The easiest way to change it is to have different values for `State` in your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample data you gave us doesn't contain negative values, here's a fiddle with some random data with negative values http://jsfiddle.net/srG6A/ take notice of this part:

```
// if 0 is not between min & max I put x-axis on the bottom
var xAxisTransform =  height; 
    if(d3Min < 0 && 0 < d3Max) {
        xAxisTransform = height * (d3Max / (d3Max -d3Min));
    }
  svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + xAxisTransform + ")") // this line moves x-axis
            .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you again for the insight, now it is slowly making sense to me.

Comment: Hi, I have managed to do the bar transform; but it is not drawing the correct height; I know why, but I just dont know where to fix it from.

Comment: man.. i need to get used to not pressing enter;
Here is the Fiddle <http://jsfiddle.net/srG6A/2/>

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski I am trying to recreate your chart but unable to do so, here is what I have created so far https://codepen.io/trainingc/pen/yzqmvZ?editors=0010#0. I tried to convert the CSV to be directly in the JS as a JSON but I am having a hard time I added a possible converted csv to a JSON inside my JS file. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what the negative value of state would mean, how about moving the y axis to create illusion of negative values

```
svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate("+width/2+",0)")   // added line
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Population");
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. The added line that you gave me moved the vertical line. But I need to move the horizontal line up, and get the bar to draw correctly.

Comment: Kept on pressing Enter. Apologies. 
Please take a look here, the x axis (horizontal) is all the way at the bottom, and the bar, eventhough some are negative, they are still drawn above the horizontal line.
<http://i.imgur.com/141H6BJ.png>